# What is the proper way to insert/update a BLOB with Play 2.3?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.3, anorm

I manage a Play server that has a MySQL database. One of its tables has a
`BLOB` column. In play 2.2, before any of the explicit `ParameterValue`
business introduced by 2.3, I was able to read/write just by injecting an
`Array[Byte]` into my query like so:

```
val foo: Array[Byte] = ???  // Doesn't matter.
SQL("update my_table set the_blob = {foo} where id = {id}").on('foo -> foo, 'id -> id).executeUpdate()
```

This no longer works. It will complain at compile time with:

```
type mismatch;                                                                  
  found   : (Symbol, Array[Byte])
  required: anorm.NamedParameter
```

It seemed Anorm doesn't know how to convert a `Array[Byte]`, so in my folly
I wrote:

```
// Now everything will work perfectly and I can get back to my day.
implicit def byteArrayToParameter(ba: Array[Byte]): ParameterValue = {
  ba
}
```

At first I didn't find any problems, but eventually I noticed that any attempt
to write to the table with the `BLOB` would:

- Hang the browser.
- Cause Play's java threads to hog any CPU cores they could find.
- Never complete the write.

Much debugging brought me back to the `implicit` function above. Logging messages
showed me this conversion was being called over and over in an infinite loop.

**Question:** How does one handle writing `BLOB`s properly with Anorm?

(or more generally)

**Question:** How does one provide proper conversion instances for types that
can't automatically be converted to a `ParameterValue`?

Thank you.

Comment: Try to use latest 2.3 release (2.3.8) or 2.4.0-RC1, as conversions for binary data have been added since 2.3.0.

Comment: About question 2, the [documentation](https://github.com/playframework/anorm/blob/master/docs/manual/working/scalaGuide/main/sql/ScalaAnorm.md#parameters) explain how to provide a custom parameter conversion. You can also use `anorm.Object` for an 'opaque' value (not recommended).

Comment: I am on 2.3.8 but was having the problem above.

Comment: Look at https://github.com/playframework/anorm/pull/29/files#diff-a93085bd27c6d7d407ef24161908c81bR252

Answer (score 2):

It seems others have had similar troubles, in particular in the area of finding any documentation for how to write these type mappings. My experience with Play is generally negative when it comes to documentation discovery.

The solution is the following, borrowed from a Grokbase thread and modified for clarity:

```
import java.sql.PreparedStatement

// Can't have top-level implicit objects, so we need a wrapper.
object foo {
  implicit object byteArrayToStatement extends ToStatement[Array[Byte]] {
    def set(s: PreparedStatement, i: Int, array: Array[Byte]): Unit = {
      s.setBlob(i, new javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob(array))
    } 
  }
}
```